# Importing function in Class from a different .py file

Tags: python-3.x, oop

Just to keep my code clean I am breaking the work into different files.

I am using the following structure

file --> class --> function

When I am calling the function from a different file I am doing the following:

```
from FILE import CLASS 
var = CLASS ()
```

so in order to call the functions in the imported CLASS, I have to write:

```
CLASS.Function_name()
```

is there a cleaner way to do it? I mean to be able to directly call the function. Thanks.-

Comment: what do you by "directly call the function"? Without `class` name?

Comment: yes to be able to do something like

Comment: from FILE import CLASS Function  so later on i can call the function directly

Answer (score 0):

It's the most useful way to call like yours in your file structure.

Answer (score 0):

if `function` is part of `class` then it's not possible to import it separately.
But you can do something like this:

```
# file 1
class Foo(object):
    @staticmethod
    def foo():
        pass

    def bar(self):
        pass

def foo():
    return Foo.foo()

def bar():
    f = Foo()
    return f.bar()

# file 2
from file1 import foo, bar
foo()
bar()
```

But this is bad way. I think that just importing class and calling function from it is much convenient (unless you want to make some stuff with result of original function in proxy function)

Comment: I am trying to use your example but I am getting the error "missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' , where do you think i should add the self?

Comment: without `@staticmethod` you need to use `self` to declare class method: `def foo(self):` and inside proxy function you will need to create instance of class in order to use such function. I will update answer